# how to start and stop the server in netbeans 6.8?

Tags: java

how to start and stop the server in netbeans 6.8?

Comment: I'm tempted to migrate this, but I don't know enough about Netbeans to know what "the server" is

Comment: embedded server? Check the 'servers' tab, right click for start/stop options.

Answer (score 7):

- Go to the "Services" tab on the left side of the screen (if it isn't visible, first select the menu Window / Services, or press Ctrl + 5)
- Open the "Servers" node in the tree
- Right-click the server that you want to start, stop or restart
- Select "Start", "Stop" or "Restart" in the popup menu

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had enough points to leave comments instead of just solutions. This is not a solution.

When you say "server"... is it a server that you have the code for are are running in the netBeans IDE or is it a service you have running in the Services tab of netbeans?